# Jquery literally writes the word "false" when function returns no data

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a jquery function to turn my links into google map links. My links are dynamic and pulled from db. So some of the links will be blank depending if that post has that data or not.

PROBLEM: If the post does not have data for that link (field), my function will litteraly write "False" on the front end instead of just being left blank (I want it to just be blank if there is no data.

I think it just needs to be made into an if / else statement but im not very good with jquery and need help

Here is the function: ( (retailers_init['full_address']) ) is the hook for the data)

```
 $('address').each(function () {
  var link = "<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + encodeURIComponent(retailers_init['full_address']) + "' target='_blank'>" + (retailers_init['full_address']) + "</a>";
  $(this).html(link);
});
```

And here is the larger function that this function (that changes (retailers_init['full_address']) to a google map link) resides in.

```
function init(retailer) {
var retailers_init = (typeof (retailer) != 'undefined') ? retailer : (typeof (retailers[0]) != 'undefined') ? retailers[0] : 'undefined';
if (typeof (retailers_init) !== 'undefined') {
    var image = $('.storeinfo ._image');

    var phone_number = $('.storeinfo ._phone_number');
    var email = $('.storeinfo ._email');
    var website = $('.storeinfo ._website');
    var title = $('.storeinfo ._title');
    var full_address = $('.storeinfo .full_address');

    image.stop().animate({
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 100, function() {
        image
                .removeAttr('style')
                .attr('src', image.attr('data-load'))
                .addClass('loading')
                .animate({
                    'opacity': '1'
                }, 200);
    });

    $('<img/>').load(function() {
        image.stop().animate({
            'opacity': '0'
        }, 200, function() {
            image.removeClass('loading');
            image.attr('src', retailers_init['image']);
            setTimeout(function() {
                image.css({'margin-top': '-' + (image.height() / 2) + 'px'});
                image.animate({
                    'opacity': '1'
                }, 200);
            }, 100);
        });
    }).attr('src', retailers_init['image']);

    title.html(retailers_init['title']);

    full_address.html(retailers_init['full_address']);
    phone_number.html(retailers_init['phone_number']);
    email.attr('href', 'mailto:' + retailers_init['email']).html(retailers_init['email']);
    website.attr('href', retailers_init['website']).html(retailers_init['website']);



 $('address').each(function () {
  var link = "<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + encodeURIComponent(retailers_init['full_address']) + "' target='_blank'>" + (retailers_init['full_address']) + "</a>";
  $(this).html(link);
});

}
}
```

Comment: which specific bit is writing out `false` ?  It clearly can't be the whole `href`.

Comment: I am using wordpress as my CMS. So if the field "full_address" is left blank than the function:           $('address').each(function () {
  var link = "<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + encodeURIComponent(retailers_init['full_address']) + "' target='_blank'>" + (retailers_init['full_address']) + "</a>";
  $(this).html(link);
});                                                           has nothing to work with and will write out false on the front end where the address would have gone instead of just leaving it blank.

Comment: It seems like the function is saying: "if you have no data to work with than I will write the word 'false' in its place"